# postgres AWS RDS - failed to create replication users

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I'm new to postgres.
I created a postgres amazon RDS database.
after creation I connected to instance via the "postgres" login and the master password I supplied while creating the RDS.

I'm trying to run this command

```
CREATE ROLE ohdsi_admin
  CREATEDB REPLICATION
   VALID UNTIL 'infinity';
COMMENT ON ROLE ohdsi_admin
  IS 'Administration group for OHDSI applications';
```

Getting this error:
ERROR:  must be superuser to create replication users
SQL state: 42501

But to my understanding I'm super user now, with weak privilages (cause of RDS)
How can I make the above command to work ?

Answer (score 10):

With AWS, you need to grant `rds_replication` to the user instead.

For example

```
CREATE ROLE ohdsi_admin;
GRANT rds_replication TO ohdsi_admin;
```

There is also information about this on the RDS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html

Comment: Thanks Thom for your reply :-) but is it possible to use 'replication' instead of 'rds_replication' role?  are these 2 roles behave exactly the same ?

Comment: RDS controls the roles differently to regular PostgreSQL as it part of its managed service.  rds_replication is used to allow for logical replication.  If you want regular streaming replication, that's managed as part of the RDS service, so managing user permissions as part of it isn't something you can do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thom for your reply. I managed to work around this issue

Comment: After running this command '''GRANT rds_replication TO <user_name>;''', do I need to restart my RDS?

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter `must be superuser to alter replication users` when using Aurora, then understand that `SUPERUSER` and `REPLICATION` attributes are not available to `rds_superuser`, which is the group your master user belongs to.

There is a separate role called `rdsadmin` who has all the permissions but is not usable by RDS users.

Replication on Aurora Pgsql is only possible with the `CREATE PUBLICATION` and `CREATE SUBSCRIPTION` commands, available from Pgsql v10 (v10.6 in Aurora). You cannot use the old way with `ALTER USER some_user REPLICATION`.

Answer (score 1):

One small detail that was not initially obvious to me: with rds_replication granted, your user still won't have "Replication" enabled in e.g. Idea database GUI, rolreplication in pg_roles will still be false, but you will be able to create publication/subscription according to the documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/database/using-logical-replication-to-replicate-managed-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-and-amazon-aurora-to-self-managed-postgresql/).
And as far as I understood, it's not possible to get real superuser in AWS RDS, but for the purpose of setting up logical replication you just don't need it.